# Iterate list to see data that comes earlier

Tags: python, list

```
a_list = [1,3,2,4]
a_data = 3

for a in a_list:
    print(a_data, a)
    if a_data == a:
        if a_data > a:
            print(True)
        else:
            print(False)
```

i need to do checking of `a_list` by which

- the value of `a_data` need to be higher than value in `a_list` - will print 'True'
- **but** the checking of that condition (a_data > a_list) has to start after the value of `a_data` equal to value in 'a_list'
- means that: value 1 in `a_list` will be ignored as the checking will start at 3.

i am not sure how to do the checking/looping

for the expected output will be

- 'True' when 3 in `a_data` met 2 in `a_list` ---- (3>2)
- 'False' when 3 in `a_data` met 4 in `a_list` ---- (3<2)

Comment: Recommend you to run this code in https://pythontutor.com/ and visually inspect what's happening in each step - then you could figure it out easily.

Answer (score 2):

If you know fore sure that `a_data` is in `a_list` you can find its index and slice `a_list` with it

```
a_list = [1, 3, 2, 4]
a_data = 3
index = a_list.index(a_data)
for a in a_list[index:]:
    print(a_data, a)
    if a_data > a:
        print(True)
    else:
        print(False)
```

Output

```
3 3
False
3 2
True
3 4
False
```

Answer (score 1):

You code cannot work as your `if a_data > a` depends on `if a_data == a`, which is imcompatible.

If you only want to get True/False for each item depending on `a_data` you can use a simple list comprehension and filter your initial condition using [`itertools.dropwhile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile)

```
a_list = [1,3,2,4]
a_data = 3

from itertools import dropwhile
[a_data>a for a in dropwhile(lambda a: a != a_data, a_list)]
```

output: `[False, True, False]`

###### using a classical loop:

```
from itertools import dropwhile
for a in dropwhile(lambda a: a != a_data, a_list):
    print(a_data, a)
    print(a_data > a)
```

output:

```
3 3
False
3 2
True
3 4
False
```